# Can I force protocol conformation in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, protocols

I'd like to do this:

`UIView <UITextFieldDelegate>*`

in swift.

Making an object that subclasses UIView also conform to the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can express `(id <UITextFieldDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate>)` using [Protocol Composition](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-XID_411)
<s>but not `(UIView<UITextFieldDelegate> *)`. except for class definition</s>.

```
// Obj-C
- (void)methodName:(id <UITextFieldDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate>)arg { ... }

// Swift
func methodName(arg:protocol<UITextFieldDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate>!) { ... }
```

Actually, an Obj-C method declared as `- (void)methodName((UIView<UITextFieldDelegate> *))arg;`, when it's bridged to Swift, you can call with any `UIView` instance.

[image]

**EDIT:**

After a little research, it seems you can declare your `func` like this

```
func myFunc<T:UIView where T:UITextFieldDelegate>(view:T) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a sub class of `UIView` and let the SubClassedView conforms to `UITextFieldDelegate`

In traditional way

```
@interface SubClassedView:UIView <UITextFieldDelegate>

@end
```

in swift

```
class SubClassedView:UIView, UITextFieldDelegate {

}
```